# Running mvn scm:status or release:prepare fails with RTC 4.x: "Error code for Jazz SCM status command - 54"

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, rtc

Both of these plugins fail the same way, which makes sense as the release plugin calls scm:status to ensure that there are no local modifications.

Here's the normal (short) error from running `mvn release:prepare`:

```
$ mvn -DworkingDirectory=/tmp/maven release:prepare release:perform                                    
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bar 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) @ bar ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **/pom.xml.backup, **/release.properties, **/pom.xml.branch, **/pom.xml.next, **/pom.xml.releaseBackup, **/pom.xml.tag
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/davisk/workspaces/foo/bar && scm status --username johndoe@us.ibm.com --password '*****'
[INFO] Working directory: /home/davisk/workspaces/foo/bar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.954 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-23T03:12:04-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/481M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project bar: Unable to check for local modi
fications
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] Error code for Jazz SCM status command - 54
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Running `mvn scm:status -X`, I can get the full underlying error message (trimmed):

```
[DEBUG] Consumed line :Workspace: (1023) "bar" (This workspace is unreachable.)
[DEBUG] Consumed line :  Could not determine the URI required to connect to the repository. The UUID of
[DEBUG] Consumed line :  the repository is _t2J8kWECEeKBH6O9T2VOlA. If you know the repository URI run
[DEBUG] Consumed line :  'login' command providing the repository URI. If not, please contact your
[DEBUG] Consumed line :  administrator.
```

Need to get this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

From some research, it sounds like Maven's RTC/Jazz SCM provider may have been built against the RTC 3.0 command line interface.

Fortunately, there seems to be a perfectly usable workaround: login via RTC's `scm login` command line tool ahead of time:

```
$ scm login --repository-uri https://fizz.example.com:9443/ccm --username johndoe@us.ibm.com
Password (johndoe@us.ibm.com @ https://fizz.example.com:9443/ccm):          
Logged in to https://fizz.example.com:9443/ccm
```

After running this once, it seems the login is cached somewhere, and the `mvn scm:status` call then works as expected.

Comment: Just a note: I'm still having some trouble getting releases to work, but I think that's a separate problem.

Comment: Here's the thread that gave me the hint I needed to find this solution: https://jazz.net/forum/questions/80805/is-one-time-connection-to-a-repository-supported-with-scm-tools-for-rtc-40?redirect=%2Fforum%2Fquestions%2F80805%2Fis-one-time-connection-to-a-repository-supported-with-scm-tools-for-rtc-40